# Base64-encoded key bytes may only be specified for HMAC signatures

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, base64, jwt

Hi i am writing JWT in Spring Boot using spring security. When i request POST on postman using below details in body section

```
{
"userName": "RAM",
"id":123,
"role": "admin"
}
```

then am getting below error

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-05-06T14:57:12.048+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Base64-encoded key bytes may only be specified for HMAC signatures.  If using RSA or Elliptic Curve, use the signWith(SignatureAlgorithm, Key) method instead.",
    "path": "/token"
}
```

i used below code for jwt builder for generator

```
   @Component
public class JwtGenerator {

    public String generate(JwtUser jwtUser) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Claims claim= Jwts.claims() 
                .setSubject(jwtUser.getUserName());
            claim.put("userId", String.valueOf(jwtUser.getId()));
            claim.put("role", jwtUser.getRole());

            String secret = "YouTube";

            byte[] bytesEncoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(secret.getBytes());

        return  Jwts.builder().setClaims(claim).signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.ES512, secret).compact();
                //With(SignatureAlgorithm.ES512, bytesEncoded).compact();
                //signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.ES512,"YouTube").compact();

    }

}
```

i used direct string value as secret key and 2 other possible combinations, but couldn't figure out the problem. i also provided the encode string as expected by DefaultJwtBuilder in JwtBuilder from below code, still no hit.

```
 @Override
    public JwtBuilder signWith(SignatureAlgorithm alg, String base64EncodedSecretKey) {
        Assert.hasText(base64EncodedSecretKey, "base64-encoded secret key cannot be null or empty.");
        Assert.isTrue(alg.isHmac(), "Base64-encoded key bytes may only be specified for HMAC signatures.  If using RSA or Elliptic Curve, use the signWith(SignatureAlgorithm, Key) method instead.");
        byte[] bytes = TextCodec.BASE64.decode(base64EncodedSecretKey);
        return signWith(alg, bytes);
    }
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 28):

The signature algorithm in your code is ES512 which uses Elliptic Curve algorithm. Since you are using a secret key, you want to use an HMAC algorithm which has the prefix "HS". So HS256, HS384, or HS512.

Change
`Jwts.builder().setClaims(claim).signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.ES512, secret).compact();`

To
`Jwts.builder().setClaims(claim).signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secret).compact();`

Comment: worked for me ! This should be marked as right answer !

Comment: Good to remember to use a secret key really really long ;)

Answer (score 0):

You switch from "SignatureAlgorithm.ES512, secret" to "SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secret", you only need username && password